# Print document from a desktop application as PDF to Google Drive directly

Tags: desktop, google-drive, print-to-pdf

In Google Chrome, when I need to save a web page or an online document as PDF to my Google Drive account, I choose 'Save to Google Drive' as a destination in the Print dialog box of Chrome.

```
Document in the Chrome ---[Print: Save to Google Drive]---> Google Drive account
```

How about desktop documents?

Is there any virtual printer driver that allows saving the printing output of documents from desktop applications (e.g. Word, Photoshop, etc) as PDF directly to Google drive?

```
Document in Word ---[Print: Save to Google Drive]---> Google Drive account
```

Note: I don't want to use PDF printer and save the output PDF in my local Google Drive folder. I'm looking for a direct method.

Comment: I think you already using the most direct method to save to google drive by saving a pdf directly into the google drive (local) folder. By the way, do you really want to give some 3rd party programmer your google credentials so they can do what you already can do in 2 steps? (Save As PDF - to your LocalGoogleDriveFolder) 
You might want to give this question directly to Google to see if they're willing to create one as if it is created by Google directly, I'm probably more willing to try rather than going through a 3rd party programmer creation.

Comment: @Darius You are right about the security issue, but a solution is needed if there is any reason that prevents the save-to-drive-folder option (e.g. public PC, Linux OS, etc). Anyway, it would be a good feature to be requested from from Google.

Comment: Also, the question is about printing any document by any software, where Save-as-pdf would rather require a pdf printer.